# Javascript RegExp dosn't recognize apostrophe on mobile iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

I have a form with three input.
The first is only number and for the other two I can accept all letters from A to Z, space and apostrophe.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number"/>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"/>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("body").on("click","#button",function(){

        let regexMessaggio = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,5}$");
        if (!regexMessaggio.test($('#number').val())){
            alert("error");     
            return false;
        }

        let regexMessaggio2 = new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ']{2,60}$");
        if (!regexMessaggio2.test($('#name').val())){
            alert("error");     
            return false;
        }
        if (!regexMessaggio2.test($('#surname').val())){
            alert("error"); 
            return false;
        }

        alert("OK");

    });
```

In every browser on desktop this code works, but not on iOS. I have tried on chrome and safari but it doesn't recognize the apostrophe.

I have also tried to change the regular expression with:
- "^([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ']{2,60})+$" 
- /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ']{2,60}$/
- "[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ']{2,60}"

Comment: I think it is because of how apostrophes are managed by the iOS when typing. It turns them into curly apos. Replace `new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ']{2,60}$")` with `new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ '‘’]{2,60}$")`

Comment: I have changed the value of the RegExp but it doesn't work

Comment: I have changed the order of chars and it works! So, at the end, the correct string is new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ‘’']{2,60}$")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the ["Smart Punctuations"](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/ios-11-smart-punctuation/) are switched on all straight single apostrophes are automatically converted to curly apostrophes. Even if you have access to the `smartQuotesType` property of UI text input fields, users may paste curly apostrophes there and you should account for them.

In the [*Regex and Smart Punctuation in iOS*](https://medium.com/@vinayganeshh/regex-and-smart-punctuation-in-ios-f36deb3503e) post, the author suggests adding `‘’` to the regex:

```
let regexMessaggio2 = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ‘’']{2,60}$/;
```

Or, in case there are any encoding issues use hex representations:

```
let regexMessaggio2 = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ \u2018\u2019']{2,60}$/;
```

Note that a regex literal notation (`/.../`) is preferable to the RegExp constructor notation when the pattern is static, i.e. you are not passing any variables to the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew for the help.
The correct string is `new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ ‘’']{2,60}$")` 
I also have find [this link](https://medium.com/@vinayganeshh/regex-and-smart-punctuation-in-ios-f36deb3503e) that can help.