# How to allow single quote in regular expression for WhitelistingTextInputFormatter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a TextField for username and want to include single quote (') within the characters such as (O'Neal Nickel). Here is my regular expression for allowing letters, space, full stop (.), hyphens (-), and single quote (').

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9 \'.-]'))
```

The regex is working for Android but not for iOS. In iOS, the TextField is not allowing single quotes. Did I get the regex right?

Comment: What is your question? Did the regex not work?  If not, tell us *how* did it not work, ideally via an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just add the quotes that are used in iOS TextField: `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9 \'’‘.-]'))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, it worked! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Your question is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57717220/3832970), please consider voting for it since you found it helpful.